# DatabaseMetaData#getTables returns nothing

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I am trying to get database information like database info, tables, views, users, schemas. But i cannot get tables. I am loading database driver from external jar file because i want to make generic database program which gets jdbc drivers from external jar file.

```
try {
            DatabaseMetaData dm = connection.getMetaData();
            /**
             * Database Info
             */
            System.out.println("Database Info\n---------------------------------\n");
            System.out.println(dm.getDatabaseProductName());
            System.out.println(dm.getDriverName());
            System.out.println(dm.getDriverVersion());
            System.out.println(dm.getDatabaseProductVersion());

            ResultSet rsCatalogs = dm.getCatalogs();
            System.out.println("Catologs\n---------------------------------\n");

            while (rsCatalogs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rsCatalogs.getString(1));
            }
            rsCatalogs.close();

            System.out.println("Schemas\n---------------------------------\n");
            ResultSet rsSchemas = dm.getSchemas();
            while (rsSchemas.next()) {
                System.out.println(rsSchemas.getString(1));
            }
            rsSchemas.close();
            /**
             * TABLES
             */
            System.out.println("Tables\n---------------------------------\n");
            ResultSet rsTables = dm.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
            while (rsTables.next()) {
                System.out.println(rsTables.getString(3));
            }
            rsTables.close();

            /**
             * columns
             */
            System.out.println("Columns of kontrol\n---------------------------------\n");
            ResultSet columns = dm.getColumns(null, null, "kontrol", null);
            while (columns.next()) {
                String columnName = columns.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
                String datatype = columns.getString("DATA_TYPE");
                String columnsize = columns.getString("COLUMN_SIZE");
                String decimaldigits = columns.getString("DECIMAL_DIGITS");
                String isNullable = columns.getString("IS_NULLABLE");
                String is_autoIncrment = columns.getString("IS_AUTOINCREMENT");
                //Printing results
                System.out.println(columnName + "---" + datatype + "---" + columnsize + "---" + decimaldigits + "---" + isNullable + "---" + is_autoIncrment);
            }
            columns.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Output:**

```
Database Info
---------------------------------

MySQL
MySQL Connector Java
mysql-connector-java-5.1.45 ( Revision: 9131eefa398531c7dc98776e8a3fe839e544c5b2 )
5.5.5-10.1.28-MariaDB
Catologs
---------------------------------

information_schema
kurs
mysql
performance_schema
phpmyadmin
seyehat
test
yolcutakip
Schemas
---------------------------------

Tables
---------------------------------

Columns of kontrol
---------------------------------
```

Note1: seyehat,test,yolcutakip are my databases
Note2: i am developing generic database program, so this code will not work only in mysql but also oracle,derby...

Comment: Given you are using MariaDB and not MySQL, what happens if you use the MariaDB JDBC driver instead? Also please show your connection string.

Comment: Can you see any tables when you `SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables`? I suspect you / your database connection might not have the required privileges to see any tables at all... The code is certainly correct

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you are right when i tried mysql database with mysql driver i get info,my conn string:  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306, i will try mariaDB jar

Comment: With the connection string `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306` you are not connecting to a specific database. That might be why you get no results. Also try to connect to a specific database and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i am testing metadata info with navicat program connection string is ok btw i cannot get anything from getSchemas() but  i can get getCatalogs() in mysql , do you know why is this

Comment: @hkn Because the concept of databases like MySQL has maps to the JDBC concept of catalogs, not to schemas. Schemas are namespace within a catalog.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel all problems has been fixed thanks you